# Regex match of all characters with multiple instances

Tags: regex

Using match, I'd like "here" to return [ee], "heree" to return [eee] and "her" to return [null].  Also "heirei" would return [ee,ii].

Assume the string is all letters with no spaces.  I imagine it involves some combination of ([\w]) and \1+,  but I can't figure it out.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't something regex can do by itself, but it can be used as part of the solution.  What language are you using?

Comment: Why should `her` return `null` ? I would expect it to return `[e]`

Comment: @HamZa I think OP wants to find all letters that appear more than once. So I'd say `her` should give `[]`. @OP, this is quite a weird format for your output. I would have asked for something like `{e: 2, i: 2}`. What do you need this for?

Comment: That's correct, I want to count the number of times a character appears for characters appearing more than once. "her" would return [null] because I think .match() returns null if no match is found.    

I'm just practicing my RegEx.  I can do it without RegEx, but was hoping that RegEx might be able to get me there easier.

Comment: @user3439903 I think you might want something like this [`(.)(?=.*?\1)`](http://regex101.com/r/iC8zM8), you will need to add one if there is a match. The problem is that you can't catch the last character since you will need a non-fixed lookbehind which is not supported in most of languages. Javascript doesn't even support fixed-lookbehinds. Seriously, if you want to learn and practice regex, this isn't a good case. Try out this [quiz](http://regex101.com/quiz/), it starts from easy to really advanced regex-fu. Another fun but not realistic "game" would be http://regex.alf.nu

Answer (score 1):

this could be done in two steps
use this pattern `(.)(?!.*\1)` and replace with nothing [Demo](http://regex101.com/r/vD8kE5)
then use the same pattern `(.)(?!.*\1)`on the result and replace with `$1$1`[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/aB4oZ8)
then sort final result

Comment: Thanks!  Impressively elegant solution.